# Compare a file with ~10 billion lines with another with 4 million lines

Tags: awk

I need to compare two files; one with over 10 billion lines and other over 4 million lines. I tried awk with following command; but it getting terminated due to memory issue. Is there any other smart way to do the same?

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$4,$5]=1; next}a[$1,$2,$3,$4]' File1.txt File2.txt`

Thanks

EDIT: Test Files

*File1*

```
1   16800236    16800237    A   G
12  104524484   104524485   C   T
```

*File2*

```
1   16800235    A   C   -0.092665
1   16800235    A   G   -0.070122
1   16800235    A   T   -0.085638
1   16800236    A   C   -0.093024
1   16800236    A   G   -0.070481
1   16800236    A   T   -0.085997
1   16800237    A   C   -0.093024
1   16800237    A   G   -0.070481
1   16800237    A   T   -0.085997
12  104524483   T   A   0.074230 
12  104524483   T   C   0.090521 
12  104524483   T   G   0.066109 
12  104524484   C   A   0.014942 
12  104524484   C   G   0.004392 
12  104524484   C   T   0.063112 
12  104524485   A   C   0.264035 
12  104524485   A   G   0.286578 
12  104524485   A   T   0.271062
```

Comment: does `File1.txt` have the 4 million lines, or the 10 billion lines? please post some sample lines from both files ... some lines that match ... some lines that don't match; are the files by any chance sorted and if so which fields are they sorted by? where did the files come from (if pulled from a database then a better idea would be to perform the join in the database)? size of each file (MBytes)? is it possible to have muliple rows with the same set of key fields (can both files have muliple lines with the same key fields)? how often do you have to do this or is this a one-time requirement?

Comment: how many lines are you expecting to match, and what would you expect the size (MBytes) to be of the output file? assuming you're loadking the smaller (in terms of MBytes) file into `awk` memory ... one brute-force idea would be to `split` said file into smaller chunks that `awk` can load without running out of memory

Comment: @markp-fuso File1.txt has 4 million lines and File2.txt has 10 million data. These SNP data from patient samples (my apologies I cannot say more as they are from human samples). None of the files are sorted. I will upload a test file in 1 hr once I reach back.

Comment: `File2.txt` has 10 *million* or 10 *billion*?

Comment: exact number 10,575,974,284

Comment: Are you limited to using awk?

Comment: @Jesse Nopes. I always used awk for such comparison that's why preferred awk. But any other working solution will be good.

Comment: I would look to use Python for this but I guess that's more a personal preference. Regardless of what you do, those files need to be sorted. Comparing unsorted data is horribly slow because you have to check everything. Also, breaking up the files into smaller chunks (i.e. 1GB) would allow you to avoid memory issues while you process each file. Then the results just need to be concatenated.

Comment: If both files are sorted, you could easily write a simple script which looks for the next item in sorted order from both files. Another approach if you are only looking for which items from A are also in B is to concatenate and sort them, and then extract the duplicates: `sort -u <(cut -f1-2,4-5 A) <(cut -f1-4 B) >duplicates`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 4 million lines I'm guesstimating `File1.txt` will require a few 100 MBytes of memory (for `awk` array storage) which should be doable with any computers built in the last decade.

This leaves `File2.txt` as a potential culprit for an *Out-Of-Memory* issue. [at 10.5+ billion rows I'm guesstimating `File2.txt` comes in at ~450 GBytes in size]

The 2nd half of OP's `awk` script applies the following for each line from `File2.txt`:

```
a[$1,$2,$3,$4]
```

While the intention is to test if this array entry exists and has a value > 0, in `awk` this will **also** create the array entry which, for a 10.5+ billion row table, is going to easily hit an *Out-Of-Memory* error in all desktop and small-to-medium workstations.

What OP should really be doing is testing if the `File2.txt` fields exist as an index in the `awk` array like such:

```
($1,$2,$3,$4) in a
```

This should limit memory usage to just what's needed to load `File1.txt` into the `awk` array.

Rolling this into OP's current code we get:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$4,$5]=1; next} ($1,$2,$3,$4) in a' File1.txt File2.txt
```

---

If OP needs to perform a lot of operations similar to this on `File2.txt` then it may be worthwhile looking into a solution along the lines of a database.

Any command line solution (`bash`, `awk`, `perl`, etc) needs to perform the equivalent of a (database) table scan of `File2.txt` each time the process is run; with a database you build a persistent index once and re-use it as often as needed.

Answer (score 0):

since the files are unsorted every comparison is independent
and you have a cross join, which is brute force and so expensive
it also means you are free split the file up any way you like (full lines) to fit in your memory and combine the results when you are done.

If small file lines are (or can be) *exact* matches to the beginning of the big files (i.e. drop the third col) you can do away with multi-string matching and use one exact string matching with fgrep or similar (that includes separators)

I think anything more efficient will have to involve some sorting in advance.